# Cannot make a connection to a SQL Server data provider using the Entity Data Model Wizard

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013

Ok, I never got the this error before...

> Unable to find the requested .net framework data provider. it may not be installed.

I'm simply trying to connect to a good old MS SQL Server and I get the above error. 
The project is just a Class Library with just a Properties and References folder. I added an `app.config` file to it.

Here are my steps for my project:

1. Add New Item
2. ADO.Net Entity Data Model
3. EF Designer from database
4. New Connection...
   Data source: Microsoft SQL Server (the Data provider then shows up as: .Net Framework Data
   Provider for SQL Server
5. Continue
   Right here, if I click "Test Connection" without any info entered about the server, I get "Test Connection succeeded". I don't know why...
6. Enter the Server name
7. Enter the userid and password for SQL Server Authentication
8. When I select "Select or enter a database name", it tries to load a database list, but it immediately goes blank. I even try typing in the database name
9. Hit OK

That's when I get the error.

Can someone **please** tell me what I need to do to resolve this?

Comment: in the connection string in the app.config, what is the providerName property in it? if it's System.Data.SqlClient make sure that this dll is located at your machine.

Comment: It does not exist on my machine... How can I install it?

Comment: what path should it reside in?

Comment: I'm looking in the following path and System.Data.SqlClient.dll does not exist here...   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient is part of System.Data (see link). http://wdinau.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/missing-system-data-sqlclient-dll/. I was able to do a using statement System.Data.SqlClient in an application. So, if that's the case, that's not the issue. Anybody else have any ideas?

Comment: I am able to connect to the same exact DB server using the sql server connection wizard in sql server management studio.

Comment: I tried adding the same exact connection (as I did through sql server management studio) with the server explorer (inside Visual Studio 2013), and got the same error I am experiencing. How come I can add the connection through sql server management studio, but not through the server explorer inside Visual Studio?

Comment: Note also, when I use the Server Explorer and try to add a new server, it gives me the error that the server name is incorrect. However, this is the exact server name as what is in SQL Server Management studio. I obviously tried to put in the user name & password of the connection which, again, is the exact same userid & password inside sql management studio.

Comment: I know this issue has something to do with the machine.config file... If anybody knows anything about it, please let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Solution solved at this link with the msg posted by Barrett.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b4f353b-77fd-427c-976b-5968abc88c13/visual-studio-2010-unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-for-sql?forum=vseditor

I hope this helps anybody else out....